# How do I get a Rails session hash variable of a user defined type to maintain it's type across requests?

Tags: ruby, session, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails v 4.2.4. I have a user defined type stored under the `lib` directory and can't seem to get session variables of that type to maintain their type across requests.  At first I thought it might be because the file wasn't able to be accessed everywhere so I added 
`config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"` to `application.rb` but the issue persists.  After redirecting to another action in another controller the variable seems to revert to a hash and raises an undefined method error when I try to call a method on it.

Is there some limitation on what types can be in the session? Method calls on the session variable within the action that created the variable work fine.

Hope that's enough information, I'm new to SO and Ruby/Rails so I'll include more stuff if needed.  Thanks.

I'll apologize in advance if this code offends someone. I feel like I'm doing a lot of wrong but since I'm the only guy in this school group project who knows Rails (which isn't saying much) I have to prioritize finishing.

This is the action that creates the session variable.  A fair amount will be moved to other functions or actions but since this is the main functionality, I wanted to get it working.  The ActiveRecord queries will be modified to only return the question ids due to the size limitations of the sessions hash which will mean more database accesses to get the rest of the questions data which is a consequence of not having enough time to figure out how to best design this thing.

```
def gross_motor
  session[:gross_motor_queue] ||= AssessmentQueue.new("Gross Motor")
  domain_queue = session[:gross_motor_queue]
  @child = Child.find(params[:child_id])
  if(domain_queue.finished_domain?)
    score_domain(domain_queue.get_domain)
  elsif(domain_queue.is_empty?)
    questions = Question.joins(:subdomain) \
    .where(:subdomains =>{:subdomain => domain_queue.current_subdomain}).limit(4)
     if(domain_queue.enqueue(questions.to_a))
     elsif #Can't retrieve more questions, score the subdomain.
       score_subdomain(domain_queue.move_to_next_subdomain)
     #redirect_to gross_motor
     end
   end
   @question = domain_queue.dequeue
   @answer = Answer.new
end
```

The html for this action.

```
<%= form_for [@child,@answer], as: :answer_of_child do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :child_id, :value => @child.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :question_id, :value => @question.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :previous_action, :value => request.path %>
  <%= @question.question %><br>
  Response:<%= f.text_field :response %><br>
  <%= @question.description %><br>
  <%= f.submit "Next" %>
<% end %>
```

The Controller and action that the form submits to which redirects back to the gross_motor action.

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
    def create
        Answer.create(answer_params)
        redirect_to params[:answer_of_child][:previous_action]
    end

    private

    def answer_params
        params.require(:answer_of_child).permit(:response, :question_id,:child_id)
    end

end
```

After the redirect from the AnswersController back to gross_motor, an undefined method error is raised at the fifth line of the gross_motor action: domain_queue.finished_domain?

And here's the class definition.  It's all just single line stuff of already defined Ruby methods but I wanted to collect the functions together to make it clear what I'm doing.  The array of strings is hardcoded right now but will later be changed to be retrieved from the database based on the domain_name.

```
class AssessmentQueue
  def initialize(domain_name)
    @question_queue = []
        @subdomains = ["Prone","Supine","Responses","Reflexes","Sitting","Standing","Mobility","Throwing and Catching"]
        @yes_count = 0
        @domain = domain_name
  end

  def enqueue(question_set)
    if(question_set.empty?) 
          return false
        end
        @question_queue = question_set.to_a
        return true
  end

  def dequeue
    @question_queue.shift
  end

  def is_empty?
    @question_queue == []
  end

    def current_subdomain
        @subdomains[0]
    end

    def finished_domain?
        @subdomains.empty?
    end

    def move_to_next_subdomain #make private?
      @subdomains.shift
    end

    def set_subdomains(subdomains)
        @subdomains = subdomains
    end

    def get_current_subdomain
        @subdomains[0]
    end

    def get_domain
        @domain
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default session values are serialized using json - types that cannot be represented in json cannot be restored.

Rails used to use marshal, which allowed any type to be serialized (subject to the class being available when it came to deserialising) but unmarshalling externally provided data is unsafe. Session cookies are signed so there is some protection against this, but using json avoids the issue entirely. You can switch back by changing

```
config.action_dispatch.cookies_serializer
```

I would try and avoid this though. Either store simpler data in the session or explicitly construct a new instance of your class from the json data in the session

Comment: Thanks, decided to go the new instance route until I figure out a better way to go about the application in general.